# automate word for windows 2007 from javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word, activex, office-automation

I have a Web application which invokes Word for Windows in order to perform spell checking on text taken from a Web form.  The code uses the ActiveXObject call to create an instance of Word and makes use of the "HTMLProject" property to create a document and add text to it.  The code works great with Windows 2003, but crashes with 2007 because Word 2007 apparently doesn't support the HTMLProject property any more.  Following is the old code; my question is, what is the simplest possible way to make this code work for Word 2007?

```
function spellCheck(textToCheck) { 
    wordApplication = new ActiveXObject("word.application"); 
    wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add("", false, wdNewWebPage)      
    wordApplication.ActiveDocument.HTMLProject.HTMLProjectItems(1).Text = textToCheck
    wordApplication.ActiveDocument.HTMLProject.RefreshDocument(true) 
    wordApplication.ActiveDocument.SpellingChecked = false wordApplication.Visible = true; 
    wordApplication.Activate(); wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Activate(); 
    wordApplication.ActiveDocument.CheckSpelling(); 
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget the semicolons! :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/worddev/thread/48045054-d906-4b5c-8042-ff31d132438d), Word 2007 no longer supports the HTML file format. You will have to update your code to reflect the new OpenXML format.

Looks like you are using Word to do spell checking. Try this: [Bring spell check window to foreground with JavaScript/JScript in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230877/bring-spell-check-window-to-foreground-with-javascript-jscript-in-windows-7)

Also, if you are able to remove the dependency of Word (and you are aren't using it to do anything else in your project), you might want to check out a PHP and JS solution: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/

Comment: Thank you, SimpleCoder.  These look like good links and I will see if I can use them to figure out how to solve my problem.  Stay tuned!

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter key by accident on that last post so it wasn't exactly informative. It is a helpful link I found by researching further the "spell check" link you supplied above. Another very helpful link is the Word 2007 object reference documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515(v=office.12).aspx). I am expecting with these links I can solve my problem today and will post again when I do.